# How to SQL insert if some values are null

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I want to insert new records into a SQL server 2008 database. Some of the column values are NULL and so I get an error. This is the SQL query i am using:

```
INSERT INTO Products VALUES(NEWID(), '" + cur.name + "', '" + cur.type + "');
```

The error is caused if my values are NULL because it reads: `NEWID(), , ;`

I could do a bunch of if statements, but there MUST be a more efficient way to do it. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the error? Are the columns nullable?

Comment: I think you have to do the conditional way to make it work. There is no auto handling of this case

Comment: Yes they are nullable. Error is "Incorrect syntax near ','."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C# does not appear to convert all null values to their equivalent DBNull values correctly.

Try something like the following

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO Products 
VALUES(NEWID(), @cName, @cType)";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cName", cur.name == null ? (object)DBNull.Value : cur.name);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cName", cur.type == null ? (object)DBNull.Value : cur.type);

cmd.Execute();
```

Your current query is prone to possible sql injection, so using parametrised query is a better solution.  It also allows for null value checks.

Alternatively, if you need the value to be empty, then use something like this

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cName", cur.type == null ? "" : cur.type);
```

Comment: This seems to be working well. But the word NULL now shows up in my gridview instead of just being a blank space like before. Is there anything I can do about that/why is it happening?

Comment: @abiNerd This is because you are not putting a null value in the database.  Earlier, the value was being converted to `''`.  If you would like the functionality, use the updated code.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to insert a `null` into the database use `DBNull.Value`